# Efficient way to search database rows from a large database table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

A my-sql database table is having millions of data records.This table consists of a primary key [say user id],serial number [can have duplicates] and some other columns which allows null values.
Eg: say the schema is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SAMPLE_TABLE (
         USER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
         SERIAL_NO NOT NULL, 
         DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100),            
         PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID)
)ENGINE INNODB;
```

Now I want to search a data row,based on the serial number.

I tried first adding a unique index including both columns [user id and serial no.] as

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX INDEX_USERS  ON U=SAMPLE_TABLE (USER_ID,SERIAL_NO);
```

and then search for the data query based on serial number as below;

```
SELECT * FROM SAMPLE_TABLE WHERE SERIAL_NO=?
```

But it didn't success and I'm getting OOM error in mysql server side when I execute above select query. Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: schema definitions would help, what datatype is the serial number, what information and how do you want to search for it. for example, exact match or partial searches. Optimisation is hard, if you want a standard 'index' answer fine, if you want someone to spend the time and suggest a solution then you must spend the time and provide all the information necessary

Comment: as your id is primary key adding another unique index including id won't give you any improvement.

Comment: And **which** part of the whole setup exits with OOM error? MySQL? Language you use to fetch MySQL records? Something else? What's your (MySQL) server configuration? What's the output of `EXPLAIN`? There's just too much data lacking in order to help you.

Comment: I have edited my question with more information.Hope it will help to find a solution for my question..

Comment: Add an index on `SERIAL_NO`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have added user_id intobthecindex you created. You just need an index on serial_no for that query.

Answer (score -1):

If you provides necessary codes,it would be better than given explainations..However first you should find the id references to seraial number,then search the column corresponding to id